# Get current screen in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

I'm trying to get the current screen in my application but I always seem to get the primary screen. I use the following code where `this` is a certain control in the App.

```
Screen.FromControl(this);
```

This also doesn't work - `Screen.FromHandle(Handle);`

However, when I use the MainWindow handle I do get the correct screen. I don't think this is the right approach and moreover I think it may suggest there's a bigger problem hidden.

Does anyone know how can it happen?

Comment: What about using `Control.FindForm` to get at the main form?

Comment: The exact location of this code is very important, completely invisible in the question, doing it too early is a fail whale.  It becomes debuggable when you use Screen.FromPoint() so you are forced to come up with the correct Point, Control.PointToScreen() required.